# ExtJS4 MVC CheckColumn not declared even if the files have been loaded

Tags: extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have a simple ExtJS4 MVC test application started with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Test/extjs-4.1.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Test/extjs-4.1.0/resources/css/CheckHeader.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/extjs-4.1.0/ext-all-dev.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/ajax/api-debug.js?apiNs=MyNamespac"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body><div id="viewport"></div></body>
</html>
```

And here is the actual `app.js` code (i've copied the `CheckColumn.js` file to `extjs-4.1.0\src`):

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });

Ext.require([ 'Ext.ux.CheckColumn' ]);

Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(MyNamespace.REMOTING_API);

Ext.application({
    name : 'Auctions',
    controllers : [ 'TestDates' ],

    appFolder : '/Test/app',

    launch : function() {


        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            layout : 'fit',
            items : [ {
                xtype : 'testdates'
            } ],
            renderTo : 'viewport',
        });
    }
});
```

I had to include the Loader, otherwise the app complained it cannot load the controller. I also had to require the CheckColumn, otherwise the `checkcolumn` xtype was not recognized.

I am not getting the following error:

> The following classes are not declared even if their files have been
>   loaded: 'Ext.ux.CheckColumn'. Please check the source code of their
>   corresponding files for possible typos: './ux/CheckColumn.js

Comment: This could be either the loader not configured correctly or a matter relating to the asynchronous dynamic loading model. Where `checkcolumn` xtype is used? Within `testdates`? If so, I'd remove  `Ext.require([ 'Ext.ux.CheckColumn' ]);` and use the `requires` config of the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should create folder `ux` under `extjs-4.1.0\src` and copy `CheckColumn.js` file there. There is always a link in ExtJs between class name and location of the file. If you class name is `Ext.ux.CheckColumn` then path must be `.\src\ux\CheckColumn.js`

Comment: I might have mislead you with my original question, but the file **is** actually at `extjs-4.1.0\src\ux`.